# UFT scripting will highlight object, but won't click it

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Why does the WebElement object highlight just fine, but the click doesn't do anything?

Browser is Chrome.

Statement are:

```
Browser("Message Validators | ETT").Page("Message Validators | ETT").WebElement("css:=SPAN.btn.btn-default").Highlight

Browser("Message Validators | ETT").Page("Message Validators | ETT").WebElement("css:=SPAN.btn.btn-default").Click
```

Comment: Hard to predict the reason behind it without more details. You might want to look into [**`FireEvent`**](https://www.joecolantonio.com/2011/06/07/qtp-how-to-use-the-fireevent-method-when-a-click-does-not-work/).

Comment: thanks.  tried that.  what kind of details are you looking for?

Comment: HTML source code might shed some light.

Comment: here's the web site... https://ttpedge.sitenv.org/ttp/#/validators

Comment: it's the upload button that is easily highlighted, but cannot be clicked... i can add the html, but figured its less effort to go there and inspect yourself

Comment: Interestingly, this is the xpath code that uft recognizes, but also doesn't highlight

'Window("Google Chrome").WinObject("Chrome Legacy Window").WebElement("xpath:=//DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/OL/DIV/DIV/DIV/SPAN\[normalize-space\(\)=""Upload File""\]").Highlight'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`Setting.WebPackage`**](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/OV_Supp_Util/Utility_Setting.htm#WebPackage) will do the trick. Tested the code on Chrome.

```
'~~> Runs mouse operations using the mouse
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2
Browser("name:=Message Validators.*ETT").Page("title:=Message Validators.*ETT").WebElement("xpath:=//span[contains(.,'Upload File')]").Click
'~~> Runs mouse operations using browser events
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1
```

Comment: Awesome.  It sure did!  Thank you Manish!!

Comment: Glad to help :)